# Compilaton error when creating a deck of cards

Tags: java

I am trying to create a deck of cards, but I am having some problems accessing the deck I create using the ArrayList.get method, I'm not sure if I have create the ArrayList of cards properly.

Card class:

```
package cardgame;

public class Card {

private String number;
private String suit;

public Card(String number, String suit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.suit = suit;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public void setSuite(String suit) {
    this.suit = suit;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public String getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

}
```

Deck class:

```
package cardgame;

import java.util.*;

public class Deck {

private String[] numberList = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
private String[] suitList = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

private ArrayList cardDeck = new ArrayList();

public ArrayList Deck() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
            cardDeck.add(new Card(numberList[j], suitList[i]));
        }
    }
    return cardDeck;
}

}
```

Main class:

```
package cardgame;

public class CardGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deck newDeck = new Deck();
    System.out.println(newDeck.get(1));
}

}
```

In the main class I am simply using newDeck.get to retrieve data to see if the ArrayList is actually populated. I am getting the following error pointing to that line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
    at cardgame.CardGame.main(CardGame.java:7)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Clean and recompile all your code. You don't seem to have a `Deck#get(int)` method.

Comment: You forgot your getter: `getCardDeck()`

Comment: public arraylist deck is wrong.. it should be public deck().. and then make a getter to return the arraylist cardDeck

Comment: I thought because I returned the ArrayList in the constructor in the Deck class, the get command would work as its a part of ArrayList already?

Comment: I strongly suggest you make your suits and number enumerations, which will help you later when you want to compare them for rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify what type arraylist stores.

Change this : `private ArrayList cardDeck = new ArrayList();`

to this : `private List<Card> cardDeck = new ArrayList<>();`

---

Also, this is not contructor and it will not be proccessed when creating instance :

```
public ArrayList Deck()
```

You have to change it to this :

```
public Deck()
```

Comment: Why not: `new ArrayList<Card>();` ?

Comment: @donfuxx that's Java 7 diamond operator.

Comment: @donfuxx: That is Java 7 syntax. It's called generic diamonds.

Comment: The main problem is because `Deck` class doesn't have a `get` method. Read the code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Acutally you are wrong, there are all "main" problems, because they do not allow to compile. However the one you mentioned is (Read the comments) used because of wrong thinking of how to use constructor. And I solved constructor issue.

Comment: I am so terribly old-school, I prefer `new ArrayList<Card>();` still :-P

Comment: I've just tested to compile this class: `import java.util.ArrayList; public class Foo { public ArrayList Foo() { return null; } }` and compiled without errors with javac. I know it is a big design problem to have a method with the same name of the class that is not a constructor, but you're allowed to do so.

Comment: By the way, usage of raw types as `ArrayList` throws a warning, not a compiler error.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - you have to think what depends on what, it is called causality. He tried to create constructor and he accidentaly created method. Therefore the weird using of created object with "get" was based on misunderstanding of using constructor, not on misunderstanding that he is using method he does not have.

Comment: Technically, the problem is because the `Deck` class doesn't have a `get` method, you just add a `get` method that returns something different than `void` and will compile. Period. That's not covered in your answer, -1. You try to cover other aspects, good! But you're not covering the main problem.

Comment: I added a new answer to sum up what has been said and also made some more improvements. If you like it, you might want to upvote the answer or even change the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the Card class immutable, because once number and suit are assigned, they will never change. Or did you ever play a card game in real life where it suddenly does?
You have to define these two arguments either way.

The `final` keyword says that, once a value is assigned to the variable, it cannot be changed anymore. Also you save a few lines of Code.

Here is the `Card` class:

```
package cardgame;

public class Card {

private final String number;
private final String suit;

public Card(String number, String suit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.suit = suit;
}


public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public String getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

// Convenient for System.out.println()
@Override
public String toString() { return suit + " " + number; }

}
```

[toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) is a method declared for each `Object` and returns a String representation of the class. I simply re-declared what this representation looks like. You can see  in the main method further below why I did this.

Now to the `Deck` class:

```
package cardgame;

import java.util.*;
// The Deck is a list of cards, so let it inherit from AbstractList
// Deck will be a Read-only list with all the syntactic sugar of lists then
public class Deck extends AbstractList {

private String[] numberList = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
private String[] suitList = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

private ArrayList<Card> cardDeck = new ArrayList<>();


// Constructor
public Deck() {
  for(String number : numberList) {
    for(String suit : suitList) {
     cardDeck.add(new Card(number, suit));
    }
  }
}

@Override
public Card get(int i) { return cardDeck.get(i); }

@Override
public int size() { return cardDeck.size(); }

}
```

Using [AbstractList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html), you get a sort of *View* on your cards list inside the `Deck`. You can then use the deck like a normal list (it's read-only, without `add(Card)` and `set(int, Card)` operations!).

For example, in your main class:

```
package cardgame;

public class CardGame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Deck newDeck = new Deck();
      // Pick the card at index 1
      System.out.println(newDeck.get(1));
      // Iterate over all cards in the Deck and print them.
      // This is basically sugar from AbstractList.
      for(Card card : newDeck) {
        System.out.println(card.toString());
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Various comments:

Deck method in Deck class is a constructor, it should not return anything.

You have no get(int) method in your deck, add one, or add a getDeck() that returns the cardDeck.

This is not an error, just a suggestion to make the code more easy to read: Replace 4 and 13 in your loops by numberList.length and suitList.length, or even better change the code to:

```
for(String number : numberList) 
  for(String suit : suitList) {
     cardDeck.add(new Card(number, suit));
```

Comment: *Deck method in Deck class is a constructor* it is not a constructor, is a method with same name of the class that returns an `ArrayList`. It *should* be a constructor by not declaring any return, because saying *it should not return anything* means that you could declare it as `void Deck` and still not be a constructor.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, very helpful!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Yes. my bad. Though it's weird to have a method with the class name, that confused me.